# strange error in android java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android, multithreading, arraylist

Hi guys I have a small problem. I'm writing a app for android and I have a part of my code like this.

```
public void loop(){

   for(Car car:carList)
        car.run();

}
```

I got the error  **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException**
I also tried using iterators in order to solve the problem quickly.
Also, I use **synchronized** since I checked the error in oracle docs and it says that could be caused by many threads using the same code.

```
public synchronized void loop(){
 Iterator<Car> carIterator = carList.iterator();
 while(cardIterator.hasNext()){
  carIterator.next().run();
 }
}
```

I don't really know why any of the solutions I found didn't work. I use this portion of code most of the cases in a background service and I use it's class that contains that method (using singleton) in the acivity too.
Thanks in advance to all the comunity

---

Thanks for the support guys,
-carList is a ArrayList of Car objects.
my car class is like this

```
public class Car{
   private int mSpeed;
   private int mDistance; //zero at first
    ........
   public void run(){
       mSpeed=getRandomSpeed();
       mDistance+=mSpeed;
       updateDistanceInDB();//here I sabe the distance in DB using a DB helper
   }
   .........   

}
```

-The error indicates that it's generated in the line that executes the method **run**
There's something strange because the app works well in another device I have.

Comment: can we see the code for `Car#run()`? You should also tell us what `carList` is

Comment: Is `carList` accessible from other threads? Or does `car.run()` happen to modify the `carList` ever?

Comment: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException comes when your trying to modify a collection object and looping through it at the same time. you may have to copy carList to other list before looping through it.

Comment: check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151956/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-in-android-animation) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533715/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-android-after-remove-elements-from-arr)

Comment: RULE #0: When asking a question about an exception, you MUST post the COMPLETE stack trace and identify the line in your code that caused the exception.

Comment: In future, please do not cross-post questions (http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30100/error-en-android-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception). For more information, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Sorry , Is this a rule? since I really needed help and I speak 2 languages.

Answer (score 2):

The most brute-force way to fix this exception is to use a [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) in place of your current `List`. This will ensure that any updates to the list during a for-each loop won't be seen during iteration, and therefore won't throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

According to its documentation:

> The "snapshot" style iterator method uses a reference to the state of the array at the point that the iterator was created. This array never changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is impossible and **the iterator is guaranteed not to throw `ConcurrentModificationException`**.

However, there may be a better way to solve your issue depending on the situation. Look for what parts of your code make modifications to the `List`, and ensure that they don't run during iteration.